# How to send link with labels in whatsapp business API

Tags: whatsapp

I'm using WhatsApp Business API and can't find a way to put links with labels in messages.

Like [Click here](https://something), in HTML. Couldn't find any reference about it in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/guides/messages

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the direct link in the body of the message, there is no option to format the link,

There are other options, you can create a button, there you can set a label and redirect link on click in the [template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates#interactive) and [interactive](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-messages#interactive-messages) message type.